# How to move a whole diagram up in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, diagram, subplot

How do I move a whole diagram in matplot when changing to a different subplot.

The problem is that I am using buttons to switch between different diagrams, but the x_labels overlap with the buttons. So is there a way to simply move the diagrams up a bit when changing diagrams so that the buttons and the x_labels would not overlap with each other?

Or is there another (better) solution to fix that?

Here is a picture in which you can see my problem:
[image]

Here is some example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import datetime


class Index(object):

    def start(self, event=None):
        ax.clear()
        ax.set_title("Start")
        x_values = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        y_values = [10, 20, 15, 1, 5]
        ax.set_xticklabels(x_values, rotation=25)
        print(ax.get_position())
        ax.bar(x_values, y_values)
        plt.draw()

    def next(self, event):
        ax.clear()
        ax.set_title("Next")
        x_values = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        y_values = [20, 15, 10, 5, 1]
        ax.set_xticklabels(x_values, rotation=25)
        print(ax.get_position())
        ax.bar(x_values, y_values)
        plt.draw()

    def prev(self, event):
        ax.clear()
        ax.set_title("Previous")
        x_values = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        y_values = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20]
        ax.set_xticklabels(x_values, rotation=25)
        print(ax.get_position())
        ax.bar(x_values, y_values)
        plt.draw()

ax  = plt.gca()
callback = Index()
callback.start()

axprev = plt.axes([0.59, 0.002, 0.1, 0.075])
bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)
axstart = plt.axes([0.7, 0.002, 0.1, 0.075])
bstart = Button(axstart, 'Start')
bstart.on_clicked(callback.start)
axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.002, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty way is to use `subplots_adjust`

```
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
```

[image]

It's dirty because you have to manually fiddle with the value (e.g. `0.2`)
until you find a number that looks right.

But then, it seems some fiddling was required to position `axprev`, `axstart` and `axnext`.

---

A better method would be to layout the axes using [`matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html):

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(10, 40) 
ax = plt.subplot(gs[:7, :])
axprev = plt.subplot(gs[9:, 18:24])
axstart = plt.subplot(gs[9:, 26:32])
axnext = plt.subplot(gs[9:, 34:40])
```

For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import datetime


class Index(object):

    def start(self, event=None):
        ax.clear()
        ax.set_title("Start")
        x_values = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        y_values = [10, 20, 15, 1, 5]
        ax.set_xticklabels(x_values, rotation=25)
        print(ax.get_position())
        ax.bar(x_values, y_values)
        plt.draw()

    def next(self, event):
        ax.clear()
        ax.set_title("Next")
        x_values = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        y_values = [20, 15, 10, 5, 1]
        ax.set_xticklabels(x_values, rotation=25)
        print(ax.get_position())
        ax.bar(x_values, y_values)
        plt.draw()

    def prev(self, event):
        ax.clear()
        ax.set_title("Previous")
        x_values = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        y_values = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20]
        ax.set_xticklabels(x_values, rotation=25)
        print(ax.get_position())
        ax.bar(x_values, y_values)
        plt.draw()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(10, 40) 
ax = plt.subplot(gs[:7, :])
axprev = plt.subplot(gs[9:, 18:24])
axstart = plt.subplot(gs[9:, 26:32])
axnext = plt.subplot(gs[9:, 34:40])



callback = Index()
callback.start()

bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)
bstart = Button(axstart, 'Start')
bstart.on_clicked(callback.start)
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh now I see, that makes far more sense in comparison what I tried. Many thanks!